# reactjs menu hide on blur with toggle class

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and need guidance. I have a menu that i needs to hide on blue by toggle class.

//MAIN

```
const [MsgMenu, setMenu] = React.useState({
    show: false
  });      
const handleOpenMsgMenu = (e) => {
e?.preventDefault();
setMenu(() => {
    return {
    show: !MsgMenu.show
    };
});
};
return (
   <Header handleOpenMsgMenu={handleOpenMsgMenu} />
   <MessageMenu showMenu={MsgMenu.show} />
);
```

// HEADER

```
function LoginHeader({handleOpenMsgMenu}) {

    <button type="button" onClick={handleOpenMsgMenu} className="header-notification-btn>MENU</button>

}
```

// MESSAGE MENU

```
function MessageMenu({showMenu}) {

     <div id="messages-dropdown" className={`messages-dropdown ${showMenu ? "show" : ""}`}>
        // MENU CONTENT
     </div>

}
```

Comment: That looks like it should work (assuming the CSS actually hides/shows the element), there are a few bits that could be improved, but what specifically is the problem? Edit: You are missing a close quote `"` at the end of your headers class names.

Comment: @DBS I need to close the menu if clicked anywhere else on the page.

Answer (score 0):

//MAIN

```
const [MsgMenu, setMenu] = React.useState({false});   
const handleOpenMsgMenu = (e) => {
e?.preventDefault();
setMenu(!MsgMenu);
};
return (
   <Header handleOpenMsgMenu={handleOpenMsgMenu} />
   <MessageMenu showMenu={MsgMenu} />
);
```

// HEADER

```
function LoginHeader({handleOpenMsgMenu}) {
return (
    <button type="button" onClick={handleOpenMsgMenu} className="header-notification-btn">MENU</button>
)
}
```

// MESSAGE MENU

```
function MessageMenu({MsgMenu}) {
return (
     <div id="messages-dropdown" className={`messages-dropdown ${MsgMenu ? "show" : "hide"}`}>
        // MENU CONTENT
     </div>
)
}
```

//CSS

```
.show {display: block;}
.hide {dispaly: none;}
```

or with css you can aniamted with transform

Comment: I used your codes but its not working, now the menu is not opening also